# WPF XAML ListBox Button click doesn't change the ListView selected index

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, listbox

I have a ListBox and inside of listbox I have buttons as items.
When I click on a button my selected index of ListBox doesn't change.

This is my code. please advise.

```
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="452" Margin="5.331,12.332,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128.667" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
        <Button Content="Theme1" >

            <Button.Background>
             <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
               <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="0"/>
               <GradientStop Color="#15FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
             </LinearGradientBrush>
           </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button Content="Theme2" >
                        <Button.Background>
             <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
               <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="0"/>
               <GradientStop Color="#15FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
             </LinearGradientBrush>
           </Button.Background>
           </Button>
        <Button Content="Theme3" >
                        <Button.Background>
             <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
               <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="0"/>
               <GradientStop Color="#15FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
             </LinearGradientBrush>
           </Button.Background>
         </Button> 
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: need to see also the ListBox_SelectionChanged function in your code behind

Comment: Also, were you hoping for the button to trigger a selection change?

Comment: I have not ListBox_SelectionChanged function yet. I need to change the selected item on appropriate button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish...but this will accomplish what i THINK you're trying to do.  This is NOT how i would do it, but if its for something very simple, it does what you asked:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding .}" Click="Button_Click">
                    <Button.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#15FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Button.Background>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Buttons = new List<string> { "Theme 1", "Theme 2", "Theme 3" };
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private string _selectedItem;
    public string SelectedItem
    { 
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    private List<string> _buttons;
    public List<string> Buttons
    {
        get { return _buttons; }
        set
        {
            _buttons = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("Buttons");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChange

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }

    #endregion

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;
        if (b != null)
        {
            SelectedItem = b.Content as string;
        }
    }

    private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```